# Exclusive volume opening

Tags: c, windows, winapi, stdio, createfile

I can open a volume "exclusively" with CreateFile by setting dwShareMode to 0:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
  HANDLE ki = CreateFile("\\\\.\\F:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}
```

I can open a volume in "shared mode" with fopen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  FILE* ki = fopen("\\\\.\\F:", "r+b");
}
```

I can open a file "exclusively" with open:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
  int ju = open("lima.txt", O_RDWR | O_EXCL);
  FILE* ki = fdopen(ju, "r+b");
}
```

However if I try to open a volume with open, it will fail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
  int ju = open("\\\\.\\F:", O_RDWR | O_EXCL);
  FILE* ki = fdopen(ju, "r+b");
}
```

After testing, this happens with or without the O_EXCL flag. Is exclusive volume
opening something that can only be done with CreateFile, or am I missing
something?

Comment: Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx `O_EXCL` does not mean "exclusive access". It is not an equivalent of `dwShareMode=0`. It gets used with `O_CREAT` to open a file only if it does not already exist.

Comment: For the record, it is probably unwise to use C runtime I/O functions with volumes.  They're not designed for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html):

> result is undefined if O_RDWR is applied to a FIFO

It appears that a volume is recognized as a FIFO in this situation. To fix:

```
open("\\\\.\\F:", O_RDONLY);
```

Or:

```
open("\\\\.\\F:", O_WRONLY);
```

Or:

```
open("\\\\.\\F:", O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY);
```